# In Mapbox studio do labels have precedence / z-orders over other labels?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

In Mapbox studio do labels have precedence / z-orders over other labels?

How does the country label stay visible as you zoom out yet railway station labels and river labels seem to fade as soon as they intersect with another label.

I understand the text size can be changed based on zoom.
But when I zoom out the settlement-label always fades out if it overlaps another label.
But country-label stays visible right up to world level.

why do country-label have priority over settlement-labels.
Its logical to us, we want to see country names at world level
but in MapBox studio is it based on a property of the feature (country, settlement)?

can I make the settlement-name e.g. London stay visible for longer and stay visible if it over laps other labels.

Another use case is railway station names disappear very early as you zoom out.
Even if I set the text size large the station name will disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in the Mapbox Streets tileset has been optimized to be as fast and lightweight as possible while balancing the need to display multiple types of information at once. To keep maps fast, some types of data are only included at certain zoom levels (for example, most hiking trails only appear above zoom level 14). If you're data are  available at the zoom level, it may be a matter of [allowing for the icons or labels to overlap](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/optimize-map-label-placement/).

Fortunately, much of the data behind Mapbox Streets comes from OpenStreetMap and you can download the data you need using a number of different methods. The process for downloading, preparing, and uploading data from OpenStreetMap to your Mapbox account is outlined below, but note that it does require you to use the command line.

Download the data you would like to work with using Overpass Turbo: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/overpass-turbo/.

You can also use the Mapbox [Tilesets API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#tilesets) to update a tileset's zoom extent in its tileset recipe. You can do this using the Tilesets CLI or by using the Tilesets API directly. For more information on zoom level configuration in tileset recipes, see the [Tileset recipe reference](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/tileset-recipe-reference/#zoom-level-configuration) and the Basic recipe using zoom levels example.

Older alternative:

Install Tippecanoe, a Mapbox tool for creating your own vector tilesets on your computer (not available for Windows but this does have a Docker instance for creating a virtual machine)

You can read more on adjusting zoom levels here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/adjust-tileset-zoom-extent/